# ModuleNotFoundError AbstractMemory when building gem5 and nvmain

Tags: gem5, nvmain

After followed build steps on [SEAL-UCSB/NVmain](https://github.com/SEAL-UCSB/NVmain), when I run

```sh
scons EXTRAS=../NVmain build/X86/gem5.opt
```

I get the following error.

```sh
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'AbstractMemory':
  File "/project/gem5/SConstruct", line 1243:
    SConscript('src/SConscript', variant_dir=variant_path,
  File "/usr/lib/scons/SCons/Script/SConscript.py", line 660:
    return method(*args, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/scons/SCons/Script/SConscript.py", line 597:
    return _SConscript(self.fs, *files, **subst_kw)
  File "/usr/lib/scons/SCons/Script/SConscript.py", line 286:
    exec(compile(scriptdata, scriptname, 'exec'), call_stack[-1].globals)
  File "/project/hsieh123/gem5/build/X86/SConscript", line 783:
    exec('from m5.objects import %s' % modname)
  File "<string>", line 1:
    
  File "/project/hsieh123/gem5/build/X86/SConscript", line 763:
    exec(compiled, mod.__dict__)
  File "/project/hsieh123/NVmain/Simulators/gem5/NVMainMemory.py", line 34:
    from AbstractMemory import *
```

Answer (score 2):

This is due to gem5 version updated and nvmain integration with gem5 is simply out-of-date.
My solution is to replace the two lines in `NVmain/Simulators/gem5/NVMainMemory.py` at Ln: 34-35

from

```py
from AbstractMemory import *
from ClockDomain import *
```

to

```py
from m5.objects.AbstractMemory import *
from m5.objects.ClockDomain import *
```

Comment: Are you able to integrate NVmain with latest Gem5 version?